# no JWS signed token in the cluster-info ConfigMap - Kubernetes v1.7

Tags: join, kubernetes, kubeadm

I am new to kubernetes and have started building a cluster on RHEL 7.3.
I have kubernetes cluster setup on the master. When i try to use

```
kubeadm join --token ancdbs.askdcvasdckasd x.x.x.:6443
```

the node is not able to join with following error message:

```
[discovery] Trying to connect to API Server "10.26.24.37:6443"
[discovery] Created cluster-info discovery client, requesting info from "https://10.26.24.37:6443"

[discovery] Failed to connect to API Server "10.26.24.37:6443": there is no JWS signed token in the cluster-info ConfigMap. This token id "a7d815" is invalid for this cluster, can't connect
```

Did notice this being listed as an issue in version 1.7 I am currently on versions shown below.

```
Kubeadm version node:
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.0", 
GitCommit:"d3ada0119e776222f11ec7945e6d860061339aad", GitTreeState:"clean", 
BuildDate:"2017-06-29T22:55:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", 
Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Kubeadm version master:
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"7", GitVersion:"v1.7.0", 
GitCommit:"d3ada0119e776222f11ec7945e6d860061339aad", GitTreeState:"clean", 
BuildDate:"2017-06-29T22:55:19Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", 
Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

I also have seen some mention about workarounds...would like to know.

How the work around can be implemeted, if possible.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the token was **expired**.

By default, tokens expire 24 hours after creation, unless you explicitly set the TTL value for the token when it is created.

If you are joining a node to the cluster after the current token has expired, you can create a new token by running the following command on the master node

```
kubeadm token create
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like this issue (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/335) which is fixed in master in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/48480 and will be fixed in v1.7.1

Comment: thanks, I was able to resolve it using the rolebinding  and role related yaml files.